# Calculate 95th percentile in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, math

This question here does not seem to help: [Calculating Percentiles (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609597/calculating-percentiles-ruby)

I would like to calculate 95th percentile (or, indeed, any other desired percentile) from an array of numbers. Ultimately, this will be applied in Rails to calculate distribution against a large number of records.

But, if I can determine how to accurately determine a given percentile from an array of numbers, I can take it from there.

Frankly, I am surprised that I haven't been able to find some sort of gem that would have such functions--I haven't found one yet.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, you want to select the values in the array for which 95% of the values are less than them? Or do you mean the values that are between 95-100% of the difference in values?

Comment: @Phrogz, not really. I want to know the 95th percentile distribution. Similar to the result of MS Excel's PERCENTILE function.

Comment: How to calculate a percentile - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile

Comment: @B5Fan74 For future questions, note that it would be helpful to link to exact definitions and to provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: @AJcodez You mean the article that says, _"There is no standard definition of percentile..."_ and that includes three+ ways of calculating it?

Comment: @Phrogz ya choose your favorite :D

Comment: @B5Fan74 If the answers below do not answer your needs, then I need you to actually define what you mean by _"the 95th percentile distribution"_. Are you talking about a histogram? Do you want to get a single value that is the cutoff point? If this point falls between values, do you want interpolation applied? Please edit your question with at least one array and an example of the output you would like from it.

Comment: I understand that there can be many interpretations of what I am looking for. I appreciate everyone's help and comments. @Justin's answer replicated the same result that MS Excel was giving as a result of the PERCENTILE function.

Comment: @B5Fan74: See my answer for gem specific solution. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to replicate Excel's PERCENTILE function then try the following:

```
def percentile(values, percentile)
    values_sorted = values.sort
    k = (percentile*(values_sorted.length-1)+1).floor - 1
    f = (percentile*(values_sorted.length-1)+1).modulo(1)
    
    return values_sorted[k] + (f * (values_sorted[k+1] - values_sorted[k]))
end

values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
p = 0.95
puts percentile(values, p)
#=> 3.85
```

The formula is based on the QUARTILE method, which is really just a specific percentiles - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/quartile-inc-function-1bbacc80-5075-42f1-aed6-47d735c4819d.

Comment: It might need to check if `values` contains a single value, so it wont break for those cases.
In my case I added this to the first line:
`return values.first if values.count == 1`

Comment: Note that the `QUARTILE` method is renamed to `QUARTILE.INC` since Excel 2010

Answer (score 19):

If your are interested in existing gem, then [`descriptive_statistics`](https://github.com/thirtysixthspan/descriptive_statistics) gem is best I found so far for `percentile` function.

**IRB Session**

```
> require 'descriptive_statistics'
=> true
irb(main):009:0> data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):010:0> data.percentile(95)
=> 3.8499999999999996
irb(main):011:0> data.percentile(95).round(2)
=> 3.85
```

Good part of gem is its elegant way of describing "I want 95 percentile of data".

Answer (score 7):

#### Percentile based on count of items

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13,14,15,20,30,40,50,60,61,91,99,120]

def percentile_by_count(array,percentile)
  count = (array.length * (1.0-percentile)).floor
  array.sort[-count..-1]
end

# 80th percentile (21 items*80% == 16.8 items are below; pick the top 4)
p percentile_by_count(a,0.8) #=> [61, 91, 99, 120]
```

#### Percentile based on range of values

```
def percentile_by_value(array,percentile)
  min, max = array.minmax
  range = max - min
  min_value = (max-min)*percentile + min
  array.select{ |v| v >= min_value }
end

# 80th percentile (119 * 80% = 95.2; pick values above this)
p percentile_by_value(a,0.8) #=> [99, 120]
```

---

<sup>Interestingly, Excel's [`PERCENTILE`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/percentile-HP005209211.aspx) function returns `60` as the first value for the 80th percentile. If you want this result—if you want an item falling on the cusp of the limit to be included— then change the `.floor` above to `.ceil`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for sharing. BTW, your `percentile_by_count` has a bug. [-0..-1] returns the entire array. Try percentile 0.999 with your solution and you'll see the issue. If you make this edit it should fix it. `(rem > 0) ? sorted[-rem..-1] : []`

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I developed in my own statistical library:

```
def quantiles(data, probs=[0.25, 0.50, 0.75])
  values = data.sort

  probs.map do |prob|
    h = 1 + (values.count - 1) * prob
    mod = h % 1
    (1 - mod) * values[h.floor - 1] + (mod) * values[h.ceil - 1]
  end
end
```

If you just want one quantile, then do `quantiles(data, [0.95])`.